# get all column of a specific entry

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am loading a database in SQLAlchemy from a XML file and I would like to access to every parameters of an entry.

For example, in my XML file, I have:

```
<AAA:Type_of_Element xxx:ID="123456">
    <AAA:Object.name>Element A</AAA:Object.name>        
    <AAA:Equipment.EquipmentType xxx:resource="&67890"/>
    <AAA:Type_of_Element.TypeGroup xxx:resource="&58463823"/>
</AAA:Type_of_Element>
```

I am getting one element using:

```
Element = session.query(getattr(m,"Type_of_Element")).all()[0]
```

I would now like to get a function listing the attributes of my Element, that is, returning:

> > > [Object.name, Equipment.EquipmentType, Type_of_Element.TypeGroup]

which function could do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way with

```
dir(Element)
```

Otherwise, I found that the following command was useful

```
Element.__dict__
```

Maybe there are better solutions but these are doing the job